# How to change the wordings for new library that show "To create a new item ..."

Tags: 2007, document-library, document

How to I change the wordings for `To create a new item, click "Add new document" below. There are no items to show in this view of the "Form_ABC" document library.` or `There are no items to show in this view of the "Documents" document library. To create a new item, click "New" or "Upload" above`

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I manage to find the answer and hopefully, anyone who need it can use the following solution:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ChangeNewMessage()
{
var a = document.getElementsByTagName('TD')
for (var i=0;i<a.length;i++)
{
    if (a[i].className=='ms-vb')
    {
        if (a[i].innerText.indexOf('To create a new item')>-1)
        {
            a[i].innerHTML = 'Coming Soon..';
            break;
        }
    }
}
}
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push('ChangeNewMessage')
</script>
```

Just paste anywhere on the aspx file that contain that new Document / List will do.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than modifying aspx page, i would recommend Modifying [SPView.ViewEmpty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spview.viewempty.aspx) property. This property contains the text you mentioned, and you can set it to whatever you like.

Note that you must change it for every view in list.

To modify it without coding or powershell, you can use [SharePoint Manager](http://spm.codeplex.com/) where you can copy out, modify in a text editor and paste back in the new value.